# Expo (web) finds app data file but Expo (android) does not

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When running with `sudo expo start --web` the following code in my `App.js` works fine,

```
await super.init(require("./assets/myfile.bin"));
```

the file is found and all is well, but when I run with `sudo expo start --android` I get the following error in the terminal,

```
Failed building Javascript bundle.
Unable to resolve "./assets/myfile.bin" from "App.js"
```

and on the Android device I get the red screen of death with the message

```
The development server returned response error code: 500
```

I'm running Expo version 3.21.5.

Does anyone know what might be going on here and how to solve it?

I found this information about [Handling Assets](https://docs.expo.io/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets/) on Expo's web page, so I added to `app.json` the following,

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "assets/*"
],
```

but still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding

```
"packagerOpts": { "sourceExts": [ "bin", "txt"] }
```

to my `app.json` file, where `bin` and `txt` are the file name extensions I wish to `require()`.